# Frame breaker only for specific sites?

Tags: javascript, frame

I use this for Anti-Frame:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
if (top.location != self.location) top.location = self.location;
```

How can I avoid to do frame break for visitors who come from Yahoo image search? They have referrer :

http://images.search.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just match the [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.referrer) and take appropriate action.

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('images.search.yahoo.com') === -1) {
    //break frame
}
```